# angular 2 - emit javascript based on the route

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs, angular2-template

This is my first angular 2 app.  I have an app that has at least 4 different templates.  One template is for the home page, one template is for the signin/register, one template is for errors, and one template is for the internal pages after you are authenticated.

I am using ASP.Net core to handle my template.  I'm using webpack to compile the ts and external libraries and grunt to handle my sass and resources.

Each template is quite different, needing different attributes on the body (solved), different css files (solved), and the most difficult, different javascript files emitted to the bottom of the page

I tried making a component and tossed my javascript in the HTML, but I soon discovered that angular 2 will strip out the script tags from components.  I found a [github post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903) that says this is by design.

> script tags should be in index.html page, or potentially loaded via a script loader (ie SystemJS) - script tags in templates will not work.

I tried importing systemjs into my project - assuming I would use it in my component - and could not get typescript to recognize it as a library, even after adding it to my webpack config file and the packages.json

```
import { System } from 'systemjs'
```

resulted in the error

> cannot find module systemjs

The problem with just slapping them in an index.html is that I'd need to swap them out which is what I was trying to do before but it wasn't working as some routes would grab the wrong template.  I'm moving to a more generic template and using components to change things, like altering the body, emitting the css, and homefully emitting the javascript.

Can anyone guide me on how to swap the javascript at the bottom of the page?  Please be specific with libraries and imports as you walk me through it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

For clarity, here are the JS sections that each template uses, for a better picture of why I need to be able to swap js files in and out.

**Home page**

```
<script src="/content/libs/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/misc/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/smooth-scroll/dist/js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

<script>//big block of javascript functions specific to only the home page</script>
```

**Internal pages**

```
<script src="/content/libs/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/jQuery-Storage-API/jquery.storageapi.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/PACE/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/assets/js/library.js"></script>
<script src="/content/assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="/content/assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/content/libs/bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/assets/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

**Error page**

The layout for errors uses no javascript

And for reference, [here is my my webpack configuration in plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/q5MMceRDrKCTRIb1MPmp/).  This is the default configuration that was generated by my Visual studio template.

I think even if I had it output multiple bundles, I'd still have to find a way to swap the bundles based on the angular 2 route.

Comment: What are those JS files exactly? Is there a reason why they can't be added to Webpack build? Obviously, you don't need to use System if you already use Webpack.

Comment: They are some external libraries used by the template, and then there is a big block of javascript- but there's no reason that can't be put into a js file by itself.  I'm not sure how to add them to webpack in a way that I could cherry pick to load or not load files based on the path within angular 2.

Comment: I added an example of the js files loaded for each template.